# self relation in sql making tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to make a database containing articles, but each article can refer to related articles. So I have an N:M relation from an article to another article. Now I don't know how to implement it. This is what I want:

Related_articles:

Article_number_1(integer), Article_number_2(integer)

Primary key:{article_number_1, article_number_2}

Foreign key: article_number_1(reference: article), article_number_2(reference: article)

But how can I specify that article_number_1 and article_number_2 both refer to article_number from table article? This is what I thought:

```
create table related_articles (
    article_number_1 integer,
    article_number_2 integer,
    primary key(article_number_1, article_number_2),
    foreign key(article_number_1) references article,
    foreign key(article_number_1) references article,
)
```

Now I know those two lines of foreign key are incorrect, but I don't know how to tell to my database that the two attributes point to the same attribute of the table article. Anyone that can help?

Comment: You can only leave out the column names, if you make the FK definition part of the column definition: `article_number1 integer references article, ...`

Answer (score 1):

After `references`, you need a full reference, that is `table_name(column_name)`. In your example it would be something like :

```
create table related_articles (
    article_number_1 integer,
    article_number_2 integer,
    primary key(article_number_1, article_number_2),
    foreign key(article_number_1) references article(article_number),
    foreign key(article_number_2) references article(article_number),
)
```

if `article_number` is the identifier in table `article`.

Comment: I'm also guessing the second FK should be on article_number_2 yes?